# C# wpf displaying information from one listbox to other

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have an listbox, with data inside(nutrition plans) and an mousedoubleclick function that opens an data about certain nutrition plan information(daily nutrition plans) in new page.  The GetDailyNutrition class gets the Id from the first listbox.

If I click on "nutrition plan A" on the listbox, it should display the daily nutritions in a different listbox(on the nutritionPlan.xaml view).

The problem is, I could not get to show the daily nutritions in the listbox.

my `NutritionPlan.xaml.cs` code:

```
    public partial class NutritionPlan : Page
{
    private DailyNutritionPlanVM _dailyNutritionplanvm;

    public Models.NutritionPlan _NPlan;

    public NutritionPlan(Object NPlan)
    {
        _NPlan = NPlan as Models.NutritionPlan;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void getDailyNutrition()
    {
        _dailyNutritionplanvm = new DailyNutritionPlanVM();
        _dailyNutritionplanvm.LoadData(_NPlan.NutritionPlanId);
        DataContext = _dailyNutritionplanvm;
    }
}
```

My `NutritionPlan.Xaml` code:

```
    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="123" Margin="88,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162">


    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Listbox where the data is taken:

```
<ListBox x:Name="NutritionPlansControlListBx" Margin="10,5" Height="282" ItemsSource="{Binding NutritionPlans}" 
                 MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NutritionPlanName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

MouseDoubleClick class:

```
        private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {            
        _frame.Content = new NutritionPlan(NutritionPlansControlListBx.SelectedItem);
    }
```

Comment: please post your code regarding: mouse double click, two listboxes, how list box items are populated

Comment: @Bijan Made Changes.

Comment: thank you. what is `_frame` in ListBox_MouseDoubleClick?

Comment: _frame is an new page where the listbox is, where I want to display the daily nutrition plan data. (i have an window divided in half, _frame is an seconds half name)

Comment: your code is very confusing, are you trying to follow MVVM pattern? or do you just want it to work? there is no vm for NutritionPlan instead it has a DailyNutritionPlanVM ...

Comment: I was trying to use MVVM, but right now it is important just to work.

Comment: How is DailyNutritionPlanVM defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your view should not know about Model. so I moved the model to view model.

Also you have to be careful with data context since each view only got one. so I changed its type to a container view model type which contains daily plans. At this point your NutritionPlan view starts with one object of NutritionPlanVM.

NutritionPlan.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class NutritionPlan : Page
{
    public NutritionPlanVM ViewModel { get { return DataContext as NutritionPlanVM; } set { DataContext = value; } }

    public NutritionPlan(Object NPlan)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //ViewModel = new NutritionPlanVM(NPlan);
        //or can be ViewModel = a VM selected from RootVM
    }
}
```

This view model needs its LoadData method to be explicitly called in order to create multiple daily plans for itself.

NutritionPlanVM.cs:

```
public class NutritionPlanVM : DependencyObject
{
    Models.NutritionPlan _NPlan;

    private ObservableCollection<DailyNutritionPlanVM> _dailyPlans;
    public ObservableCollection<DailyNutritionPlanVM> DailyPlans { get { return _dailyPlans; } }

    public void LoadData(Models.NutritionPlan _NPlan)
    {
        var dnpVM = new DailyNutritionPlanVM(_NPlan.NutritionPlanId);
        _dailyPlans.Add(dnpVM);
    }

}
```

You need another view model containing an observable collection for all nutrition plans.

```
public class RootVM : DependencyObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<NutritionPlanVM> _nutritionPlans;
    public ObservableCollection<NutritionPlanVM> NutritionPlans { get { return _nutritionPlans; } }

    //vm data populated in constructor
    public RootVM()
    {
        _nutritionPlans.Add([add all nutrition plans]);
    }

}
```

Now for the binding root, there should be a view corresponding to this RootVM. (e.g., MainWindow). in the constructor of that view you need `DataContext = new RootVM()`

Now that everything is in place, you can bind to the currently selected item of the first listbox, and use that item to extract view model information:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=NutritionPlansControlListBx, Path=SelectedItem.DailyPlans}"/>
```